# Permutations w/ discrete math. Choosing the right method

Tags: algorithm, permutation, counting, discrete-mathematics

> Let f ≥ 4 and m ≥ 4 be integers. There are f female students and m
>   male students that are eligible to be members on the council.
>
> Determine the number of way to choose eight members for the council
>   out of these f + m students, such that the number of female members is
>   equal to the number of male members.

This is a question out of my textbook's practice problems which has no answer keys. It's hard to know if I'm doing things right without being able to confirm my answer. Was wondering if someone can help me out with this.

We have 8 possible members, if there are equal male and female then there has to be 4 male members and 4 female members. Would the answer to this problem simply be a permutation problem. 8 choose 4?

```
         8!
p  = -----------
      4! (4)!
```

Comment: That proposed solution does not depend on `f` or `m`, which would mean that  the number of ways of selecting a council in a class with 8 total members is the same as the number of possible councils in a class of 100. Does that seem plausible to you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about combinatorics

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** C(f, 4) × C(m, 4)

You need 8 members, with exactly 4 being female and exactly 4 being male. So break the problem down into first picking the 4 females and then picking the 4 males.

To find the females to be on the council there are C(f, 4) possible ways. Why? You need to [pick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) exactly 4 females from a pool of f that are available, and you don't care about the order in which they are chosen. By the same reasoning there are C(m, 4) ways for selecting the males for council.

By the [multiplication principle of counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) you just need to multiply every possible way of picking the females with every possible way of picking the males. So you have:

*total choices*
= *choices for females* × *choices for males*
= C(f, 4) × C(m, 4)

---

*NB: C(n, k) denote the [binomial cofficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), the number of ways to choosing k items from n where the order does not matter. You don't care about the order in which members have been selected for council, so 
it becomes a "[combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)" problem, not a "[permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)" problem.*